# Subtract number from ResponseAsXml SoapUI

Tags: xml, soapui

I have a JDBC test step that I'm calling the value of "46680.06"

```
${FPL_RANGES#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/FPL_400_001[1]}
```

The above I would like to subtract 3000 from it.

I just don't know how to apply the subtraction part.

Thank you,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simply `Xpath` subtract operator which is `-`, so add `-3000` to your XPath as follows:

`${FPL_RANGES#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/FPL_400_001[1]-3000}`

Additionally normally in `JDBC TestStep` the xml result has only one `<Results>` and one `ResultSet` node, so you can use (it's equivalent to yours):

`${FPL_RANGES#ResponseAsXml#//Results/ResultSet/Row[1]/FPL_400_001[1]-3000}`

Hope this helps,

Comment: You can safely trim it down to `${FPL_RANGES#ResponseAsXml#//FPL_400_001 - 3000}`. In SoapUI XPath that matches multiple nodes will always pick the first one.

Comment: Thank you both!  The JDBC response will return a number of rows - so I will  be using other rows in different use cases.